# Running Qt5 GUI in Docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, qt5, vnc

I am trying to run a GUI app (V-REP) inside docker inspired by what has been suggested at:

http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/

But I'm getting the error:

> QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

I have read answers to similar questions and tried using [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) and xauth but keep getting the same error. Im using the [Makefile and Dockerfile from here](https://github.com/ahundt/install-clang).

I'd appreciate any suggestions and also appreciate instructions on how to actually use a VNC program to connect, since I'm not familiar with that process. Thanks.

The program is run [from the makefile](https://github.com/ahundt/install-clang/blob/master/Makefile):

```
make docker-run-vrep
```

If they are useful, here are the [current docker setup steps](https://github.com/ahundt/robone/blob/develop/doc/howto/RunInDocker.rst).

Comment: I have built your image, but your Dockerfile lacks a CMD or ENTRYPOINT, and you have not shown how your start oyur container

Comment: @user2915097 make docker-run-vrep

Answer (score 0):

Try this before running the app:

```
xhost +
```

After the app starts, you may want to:

```
xhost -
```